# Add ComboBox to TableColumn and Bind To Row Data

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a simple form as shown here:

[image]

**Here is the MCVE code.**

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TableView<TemplateColumn> tblColumns;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TemplateColumn, Integer> colColumnIndex;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TemplateColumn, String> colColumnName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TemplateColumn, String> colMappedTo;

    private Template sourceTemplate;
    private Template destinationTemplate;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        createSampleData();

        // Initialize the table
        colColumnIndex.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("columnIndex"));
        colColumnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("columnName"));
        colMappedTo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("destinationColumnIndex"));

        tblColumns.setItems(sourceTemplate.getColumns());

        ComboBox<TemplateColumn> cboMappedColumns = new ComboBox<>();
        cboMappedColumns.setItems(destinationTemplate.getColumns());

    }

    private void createSampleData() {

        destinationTemplate = new Template();
        destinationTemplate.setTemplateName("Output");
        destinationTemplate.setColumns(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new TemplateColumn("Destination 0", 0, -1),
                new TemplateColumn("Destination 1", 1, -1),
                new TemplateColumn("Destination 2", 2, -1),
                new TemplateColumn("Destination 3", 3, -1))
        );

        sourceTemplate = new Template();
        sourceTemplate.setTemplateName("Input");
        sourceTemplate.setColumns(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new TemplateColumn("Source 0", 0, 3),
                new TemplateColumn("Source 1", 1, 1),
                new TemplateColumn("Source 2", 2, 0),
                new TemplateColumn("Source 3", 3, 2))
        );
        sourceTemplate.setDestinationTemplate(destinationTemplate);

    }
}
```

**Template.java**

```
public class Template {

    private final SimpleStringProperty templateName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleStringProperty destinationTemplateName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Template> destinationTemplate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    // The list of TemplateColumns
    private List<TemplateColumn> columns;

    public Template() {
        templateName.set("NEW");
    }

    public Template(ArrayList<TemplateColumn> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty templateNameProperty() {
        return templateName;
    }

    public void setTemplateName(String templateName) {
        this.templateName.set(templateName);
    }

    public String getDestinationTemplateName() {
        return destinationTemplateName.get();
    }

    public void setDestinationTemplateName(String destinationTemplateName) {
        this.destinationTemplateName.set(destinationTemplateName);
    }

    public ObservableList<TemplateColumn> getColumns() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(columns);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty destinationTemplateNameProperty() {
        return destinationTemplateName;
    }

    public Template getDestinationTemplate() {
        return destinationTemplate.get();
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Template> destinationTemplateProperty() {
        return destinationTemplate;
    }

    public void setDestinationTemplate(Template destinationTemplate) {
        this.destinationTemplate.set(destinationTemplate);
    }

    public void setColumns(List<TemplateColumn> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public TemplateColumn getReportColumn(int index) {
        for (TemplateColumn col : columns) {
            if (col.getColumnIndex() == index) return col;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return templateName.get();
    }
}
```

**TemplateColumn.java**

```
public class TemplateColumn {

    private final SimpleStringProperty columnName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty columnIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty destinationColumnIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

    public TemplateColumn(String columnName, int columnIndex, int destinationColumnIndex) {
        this.columnName.set(columnName);
        this.columnIndex.set(columnIndex);
        this.destinationColumnIndex.set(destinationColumnIndex);
    }

    public int getDestinationColumnIndex() {
        return destinationColumnIndex.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty destinationColumnIndexProperty() {
        return destinationColumnIndex;
    }

    public void setDestinationColumnIndex(int destinationColumnIndex) {
        this.destinationColumnIndex.set(destinationColumnIndex);
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty columnNameProperty() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName.set(columnName);
    }

    public int getColumnIndex() {
        return columnIndex.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty columnIndexProperty() {
        return columnIndex;
    }

    public void setColumnIndex(int columnIndex) {
        this.columnIndex.set(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return columnName.get();
    }
}
```

**The Issue**

Basically, what I need is the `cboMappedColumns` ComboBox to be shown in the `Mapped To` column of each row in the table, with its value bound (bidirectionally) to the `TemplateColumn` whose `columnIndex` matches the `destinationColumnIndex` of the row's source `TemplateColumn`.

So, instead of displaying "3" in the first row, it would be a ComboBox with the value "Destination 3" selected instead.

**Note:** This is my third attempt at posting a valid question; please let me know if I'm still missing something.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: as always, you need a cell that uses a combo and set a callback which creates it as the column's cellFactory (there's a ComboBoxTableCell that you can use) - so don't quite understand what the problem is, nothing special ... As to posting the same question repeatedly: better not (everybody needs to re-read and make the connection to earlier questions) - instead, edit a question and add details as needed :)

Comment: Thank you, @kleopatra, but how do I bind the value of the combobox to a `TemplateColumn` based on one of its properties? As in, how do I search through all the items in the combobox and find the one with the correct `columnIndex` property?  I guess that's my main question.

Comment: hmm .. dont understand: why do you want to "bind" anything (which you dont show in your code, btw ;) - the comboCell will show and edit the data of its content just as any other cell ..

Comment: The Combo Box selection needs to be bound with the row data's `destinationColumnIndex` property. So, changing the combobox value should, essentially, execute `rowData.setDestinationColumnIndex(cboDestinationColumn.getValue().getColumnIndex());`.

Comment: And vice versa: each row's combobox should initially be set to the `TemplateColumn` in the Combobox whose `columnIndex` matches the row data's `destinationColumnIndex ` property value.

Comment: then the column should have the property that needs to be edited - don't fight the system, you'll loose ;) Instead, model the data such that it fits the context that the control (here that's the tableView with its columns) expect. Off now, need some sleep :)

Comment: okay, at least I understand what you are trying to do (I think ;) - not supported, you can't mix types in one column. You do so twice: 1) colToMap has type String and bound to destinationColumnIndex which is-a Integer 2) the combo (which is not a Cell but must be!) has items of type TemplateColumn in a column of type String. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

`setCellFactory` for the column that will contain a `ComboBox`:

- Create a new `ComboBox` of your type, and bind it's value property bidirectionally to the desired property in your class.
- Set the created `ComboBox` as the graphic of the row.

I hope the following example will help you solve your problem.

[image: Output]

**Controller:**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Employee> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, CompanyType> companyTypeColumn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getName());
        });

        companyTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return param.getValue().companyTypeProperty();
        });

        companyTypeColumn.setCellFactory((column) -> {
            return new TableCell<Employee, CompanyType>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(CompanyType item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null && !empty) {
                        ComboBox<CompanyType> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(CompanyType.values()));

                        Employee employee = (Employee) getTableRow().getItem();
                        comboBox.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(employee.companyTypeProperty());

                        setGraphic(comboBox);
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        table.getItems().add(new Employee("Foo", CompanyType.PRIVATE));
        table.getItems().add(new Employee("Bar", CompanyType.PUBLIC));
        table.getItems().add(new Employee("John", CompanyType.PUBLIC));
    }

}
```

**Employee Class:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Employee {

    private String name;

    public Employee(String name, CompanyType companyType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.setCompanyType(companyType);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<CompanyType> companyType = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public CompanyType getCompanyType() {
        return companyType.get();
    }

    public void setCompanyType(CompanyType value) {
        companyType.set(value);
    }

    public ObjectProperty companyTypeProperty() {
        return companyType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "name=" + name + ", companyType=" + companyType + '}';
    }

}
```

**CompanyType Class:**

```
public enum CompanyType {
    PRIVATE, PUBLIC;
}
```

Comment: There are several problems with your code (in no particular order): a) you re-create a new combo in each call to updateItem b) a cell must not change data under-the-feet (as a binding does), instead the setup must use the edit mechanism c) your example is different from OPs setup in that the type of of combo's items is the same as column type - that's the right thingy to do, but doesn't solve the OPs problem ;)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try to edit my answer accordingly.